# How to create func filter for search on UIsearchbar

Tags: swift3, uisearchbar

This is my code to create UIsearchbar.
I want to create function filter by this search bar work on UItableview

```
 //Make sure to import UIKit import Foundation import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

      var searchController = UISearchController()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
          //Setup search bar
          searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
          searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
          definesPresentationContext = true
          //Set delegate
          searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
          //Add to top of table view
          tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
     } } extension ViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
     func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
          print(searchController.searchBar.text!)
     } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps on how to start with it.

> - Create two data sources.
> - One keeps all data(dataSourceFull) and other keeps filtered data(dataSourceFiltered).
> - On text change of UISearchBar, use NSpredicate to filter the original datasource(dataSourceFull) and keeps the filtered data in
>     (dataSourceFiltered).
> - Bind filtered data(dataSourceFiltered) with tableview and reload it.
> - In case, on search text clear, empty the filtered data source.